# Make a db historic?

Tags: angularjs, list

The problem is that first : I can't find the english word for this.

This, is simply the list of the last db entries.

I would like to generate a list of last db entries, but when a new entry come in, the last disappears, etc etc.

How can I make it ? Is there a word for it so I can look for a guide/tutorial ?

Comment: its called Data Versioning or Data Revisioning.

Comment: thx, gonna look for it.

Comment: Not giving me anything :/ I'm just talking about a ng-repeat finally, that checks db, or when there's a db entry it automatically send it to the view.
Isn't there any guide for it ?